# how are child class components in reactjs are called .Can any one tell me the flow of the following program

Tags: reactjs

program:-

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 

// Parent Component 
class Parent extends React.Component{ 
    render(){ 
        return( 
                <div> 
                    <h2>You are inside Parent Component</h2> 
                    <Child name="User" userId = "5555"/> 
                </div> 
            ); 
    } 
} 

// Child Component 
class Child extends React.Component{ 
    render(){ 
        console.log(this.props); 
        return( 
                <div> 
                    <h2>Hello, {this.props.name}</h2> 
                    <h3>You are inside Child Component</h3> 
                    <h3>Your user id is: {this.props.userId}</h3> 
                </div> 
            ); 
    } 
} 

ReactDOM.render( 
    // passing props 
    <Parent />, 
    document.getElementById("root") 
);
```

I can see that the parent class is been called using the render method dint have any idea how the class component child is called.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation from the React docs:

> Components can refer to other components in their output. This lets us use the same component abstraction for any level of detail. A button, a form, a dialog, a screen: in React apps, all those are commonly expressed as components.

Your `Parent` component refers to the `Child` component; when `Parent` is rendered, `Child` is as well, with the props `name` and `userId`.

[Composing Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components)